# xConnect facet value persistence in multisite, when trying to open both sites in the same window but diff tabs

Tags: sxa, xconnect, contact-facets

I have county-specific multisite and configured correctly in site settings, As mentioned below.

[image]

Secondly, on the home page, I'm using some contact from the custom facet, and the source of data is site-specific,

The issue is when I open AU site, I can see data from the xConnect (Au Site), but when I open NZ site in the same tab, It's showing data from AU data source.

It's working fine If I open in a new window or in the incognito mode (Au site will show AU xConnect data, and NZ site will show NZ xConnect data), do I need to configure DNS or something else?

If anyone found a similar issue, I will appreciate if you can share your finding.

Answer (score 1):

After a bit of investigation, I have found the solution this is because of missing separate domain for multisite, Sitecore relies on cookies to track anonymous contacts - specifically the SC_ANALYTICS_GLOBAL_COOKIE cookie.

If you have a single domain and want to keep multiple sites with the diff virtual folders, this issue will occur, In that case, You can configure the domain of the tracking cookie (SC_ANALYTICS_GLOBAL_COOKIE) if you do not want it to be the default domain, As mentioned here - https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/90/platform-administration-and-architecture/en/configure-the-analytics-cookie-domain.html